# ODR violation when name-lookup finds a different declaration

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I've been thinking of the following. Consider two files:

A.cpp:

```
template<class T> void g(T) {}

inline void f() { g(1); }
```

B.cpp:

```
template<class T> void g(T) {}
void g(int) {}

inline void f() { g(1); }
```

Without `void g(int) {}` this program is 100% valid. With `void g(int) {}`, `g(1)` resolves to the template version in A.cpp and to the non-template in B.cpp.

Does this program violate ODR? Why?

Comment: This is where the `include` mechanism truly shines :/

Comment: @Matthieu: this is where the question came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does. In the exception for `inline` functions it's specified that not only shall the definitions of the inline function consist of exactly the same token sequence but that all the corresponding identifiers in the function definition which name entities outside of the function definition must refer to the same entity (with a few minor exceptions, such as referring to const objects with internal linkage with the same definition being allowed). [see ISO/IEC 14882:2003 3.2/5]